# Example of an algorithm whose runtime is O(n^2 log n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have to construct an algorithm where it's upper bound is O(n<sup>2</sup> log n). Can anyone provide any examples on what an O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) algorithm would look like? I cannot seem to wrap my mind around it.

My mental image of it would be two nested for loops and within the second loop a log n operation is performed. Is this correct?

Comment: The question better fits https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to get a runtime of O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) in an algorithm. Here's a sampler.

- ***Sorting a list of n<sup>2</sup> items efficiently.*** For example, if you take n items, form all n<sup>2</sup> pairs of those items, and then sort them using something like heapsort, the runtime will be O(n<sup>2</sup> log n<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>2</sup> log n). This follows from properties of logarithms: log n<sup>2</sup> = 2 log n = O(log n). More generally, running an O(n log n)-time algorithm on an input of size n<sup>2</sup> will give you an O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) runtime.
- ***Running Dijkstra's algorithm on a dense graph using a binary heap***. The runtime of Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph with n nodes an m edges, using a binary heap, is O(m log n). A dense graph is one where m = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), so Dijkstra's algorithm would take time O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) in this case. This is also the time bound for running some other graph algorithms on dense graphs, such as Prim's algorithm when using a binary heap.
- ***Certain divide-and-conquer algorithms***. A divide-and-conquer algorithm whose recurrence is T(n) = 2T(n / √2) + O(n<sup>2</sup>) has a runtime of O(n<sup>2</sup> log n). This comes up, for example, as a subroutine in the Karger-Stein minimum cut algorithm.
- ***Performing n<sup>2</sup> searches on a binary tree of n items.*** The cost of each search is O(log n), so this would work out to O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) total work. More generally, doing any O(log n)-time operation a total of O(n<sup>2</sup>) times will give you this bound.
- ***Naive construction of a suffix array***. A suffix array is an array of all the suffixes of a string in sorted order. Naively sorting the suffixes requires O(n log n) comparisons, but since comparing two suffixes can take time O(n), the total cost is O(n<sup>2</sup> log n).
- ***Constructing a 2D range tree.*** The range tree data structure allows for fast querying of all points in k-D space within an axis-aligned box. In two dimensions, the construction time is O(n<sup>2</sup> log n), though this can be improved to O(n log n) using some more clever techniques.

This is, of course, not a comprehensive list, but it gives a sampler of where O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) runtimes pop up in practice.

Comment: Thank you this helped

Answer (score 3):

Technically, any algorithm which is asymptotically faster than `n^2 log n` is called `O(n^2 log n)`. Examples include "do nothing" algorithm `Theta(1)`, binary search `Theta(log n)`, linear search `Theta(n)`, bubble sort `Theta(n^2)`.

The algorithm you describe would be `O(n^2 log n)` too while also being `Omega(n^2 log n)` and thus `Theta(n^2 log n)`:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        # binary search in array of size n
```

Comment: Thank you this helped

Answer (score 1):

One approach to constructing a O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) algorithm is to start with a O(n<sup>3</sup>) algorithm and optimize it so one of the loops runs in log n steps instead of n.

That could be non-trivial though, so searching Google turns up the question [Why is the Big-O of this algorithm N^2*log N?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28593290/1288) The problem there is:

> Fill array a from a[0] to a[n-1]: generate random numbers until you
> get one that is not already in the previous indexes.

Even though there are faster algorithms to solve this problem, the one presented is O(n<sup>2</sup> log n).

Comment: Thank you this helped